# Making a tree with hash input

Tags: ruby, tree

I initialized a tree using a nested hash as input, but when I recursively call `Tree.new` on the children, it doesn't seem to pass each child as a hash. As a pretty ugly, but working, alternative, I translated everything to arrays.

Is there a way to preserve the hash?

I'm doing this exercise using Ruby 1.9.3, so I can't use Ruby 2.0.0's `to_h` method.

```
class Tree
  attr_accessor :node_name, :children

  def initialize(arr)
    arr = arr.to_a unless arr.is_a?(Array)
    arr.flatten!
    @node_name = arr.first
    @children = []
    arr.last.each { |c| @children << Tree.new(c) }
  end

  def visit(&block)
    block.call self
  end

  def visit_all(&block)
    visit &block
    children.each { |c| c.visit_all(&block) }
  end
end

family_tree = Tree.new({'grandpa' => { 'dad' => { 'child 1' => {}, 'child 2' => {} },
                                      'uncle' => {'child 3' => {}, 'child 4' => {} } } })

family_tree.visit_all { |node| p node.node_name }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- The `initialize` method of a class should be its most basic and fundamental constructor, don't use it as a "helper". A tree has a name and some children, so these should be the arguments. You want to construct a Tree from a hash to make things easier for the caller? then create a helper classmethod, for example `Tree::new_from_hash(hash)`.
- `Tree#visit`. That's an imperative construct, I'd write first the functional ones (which can also be used imperatively if needed).
- `node.node_name`: That repetition is a cue that `node_name` is redundant, `name` is enough.
- (Subjective) I prefer to write hash literals without losing indentation space.

I'd write (I'd inherit from `Struct` to save some lines, not really needed):

```
class Tree < Struct.new(:name, :children)
  def self.new_from_hash(hash)
    name, children_hash = hash.first
    children = children_hash.map { |k, v| Tree.new_from_hash({k => v}) }
    Tree.new(name, children)
  end

  def visit_all(&block)
    yield(self)
    children.each { |c| c.visit_all(&block) }
  end
end

family_tree = Tree.new_from_hash({
  'grandpa' => {
    'dad' =>   {'child 1' => {}, 'child 2' => {}},
    'uncle' => {'child 3' => {}, 'child 4' => {}},
  },
})

family_tree.visit_all { |node| puts node.name }
```

Additional notes:

- Include module `Enumerable` and implement `Tree#each` so you can use all enumerable methods for you trees. Note that enumerable methods assume a single-level iteration, so you'd still need custom methods (like `visit_all`/`map_all`) that perform nested operations.
- If that's a learning code I'd explore this path: create a `NestedEnumerable` module -very similar to `Enumerable`- which would provide some `xyz_all` (or `xyz_nested`, whatever) methods. Like `Enumerable`, you would only be required to implement the "each" method (i.e. `each_all`).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I am doing this as a learning exercise. https://gist.github.com/yubrew/5175022 I implemented the Enumerable, but not really sure what to do to make NestedEnumerable. I'm not sure how to recognize 'children' inside NestedEnumerable. Is there some tutorial or a hint you can give me?

Comment: Ruby is not very orthodox on that matter, if you include `Enumerable` you get methods on each element individually, that may or may not be useful. On custom data containers the idea is that map/select/reject/... equivalents return the same input structure, with the block applied/filtering the value of each node (here you only have `name` to play with). That's for example how Haskell and Functors work (see `fmap` for a `Tree` for example). If you're not familiar with the language is quite a task to understand it though. http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids

Comment: At the end it all depends on what operations you want on the trees. `visit` has the problem that only works through side-effects. That's a pity in a language like Ruby. More on functional programming: https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming